# View error: Can't find field 'field name' in the following view parts composing the view of object model 'object name'

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

My company's client has backed up the database from their server and gave dump file to restore it locally on my machine, on exactly the same versions (7.0). While the backup and restore process works without errors, I get the following **OpenERP Warning** when opening the accounts module:

```
"View error. Can't find field 'amount_net' in the following view parts  
composing the view of object model 'account.invoice':
* account.invoice.form
```

Either you wrongly customized this view, or some modules bringing those views are not compatible with your current data model

The big problem is that I cannot open any invoice after the warning! 
I even deleted that field in the postgres database, restarted server and updated the module but still it doesn't get deleted here in openerp. The company also provided the complete addons directory,but they have not made any changes in the source code. I have attached that image[image]

Comment: same version means, did you copied openerp folder from company server or you just downloaded v7 ?

Comment: copied openerp folder from their comp server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install advance and additional discount module which can be downloaded from odoo apps.